# Angular build error while importing ngsw-config.json Error: export 'assetGroups'.'find' (imported as 'ngswConfig') was not found

Tags: json, angular

In the Angular component code I am trying to read property from ngsw-config.json by importing the json file. Build fails with error. I have followed following steps -

```
//app.component.ts
import * as ngswConfig from '../../ngsw-config.json';

ngoninit() {
    console.log(ngswConfig.assetGroups.find(x => x.name === 'app'));
}
```

Error during ng build -

./src/app/app.component.ts:55:18-45 - **Error: export 'assetGroups'.'find' (imported as 'ngswConfig') was not found in '../../ngsw-config.json' (possible exports: 0, 1)**

Options tried -
have following compiler options in **tsconfig.json**
**"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,**

Additional information -
**Angular version 12 & 16
NodeJS - v20.9.0**

Comment: please share the contents of `ngswConfig`

Comment: It's the default file generated from ng add @angular/pwa